# Preparing data for graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like some help in order to prepare my data gathered from the database for charting.
I have a Browser model where I store all the data.

From each model I want to select the name attribute, I will put a color according an integer attribute in the model (for example if integer is 1,  color => "#4572A7") and the y attribute from the model.

Can someone provide an example of the most efficient way to achieve this data format?

Final format of the data:

```
            [
              {
                 :name=> 'Firefox',
                 :y=> 1,
                 :color => "#4572A7"
              },
              {
                 :name=> 'IE',
                 :y=> 1,
                 :color => "#AA4643"
              },
              {
                 :name=> 'Chrome',
                 :y=> 1,
                 :color => "#89A54E"
              },
              {
                 :name=> 'Safari',
                 :y=> 1,
                 :color => "#80699B"
              },
              {
                 :name=> 'Opera',
                 :y=> 1,
                 :color => "#3D96AE"
              },
              {
                 :name=> 'Others',
                 :y=> 1,
                 :color => "#DB843D"
              }
           ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a method that does the number-to-color translation and have something like

```
@browsers.to_json(methods: [:the_method_that_translates_numbers_to_colors], only: [:name, :y])
```

Hope that helps,

NHI

Comment: How will this create the `:color` field?

Comment: You need a "field" on your database or you need it to be shown in the json response? If it's just on the response, that will work. Look at this, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json